# unable to connect XMPP server using stropher.js

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, strophe

When i connect to XMPP server using stropher.js it give connection status as 1 = The connection is currently being made

What is the problem for this status.

code is as below for connection.

it return me connecting status.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#login_dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Connect to XMPP',
    buttons: {
        "Connect": function () {
            $(document).trigger('connect', {
                jid: $('#jid').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            });                
            $('#password').val('');
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
});

$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://127.0.0.1:5280/http-bind");
    //"http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind");

        conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {           
    if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {          
        $(document).trigger('connected');
    } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
        Hello.log("Status DISCONNECTED.");
        $(document).trigger('disconnected');
    }
});

 Hello.connection = conn;
});

 $(document).bind('connected', function () {
    // inform the user
    Hello.log("Connection established.");

   Hello.connection.addHandler(Hello.handle_pong, null, "iq", null, "ping1");

   var domain = Strophe.getDomainFromJid(Hello.connection.jid);

   Hello.send_ping(domain);

 });

 $(document).bind('disconnected', function () {
   Hello.log("Connection terminated.");

   // remove dead connection object
  Hello.connection = null;
});
```

I am using phone gap.

Thanks

Comment: Hi - you will need to provide more information for anyone to be able to understand your problem. Also please say what you have tried to resolve this problem yourself as this will help users if they have had a similar problem themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your code at `Stroph.Connection` is wrong. First, you verify that passing URL parameter to `Stroph.connnection("URL")` is valid  or not.

```
$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {
    var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://example.com:7070/http-bind");
    //"http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind");
```

- In the code above, **7070** is for unsecured port for HTTP binding connection on Openfire.
- If your issue is not solved, please provide which XMPP server you are using in your PhoneGap application.